# SQL Limit error with JavaDB

Tags: sql, limit, javadb

Firstly, I'm new to SQL - not so new to Java anymore.

Secondly, I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 with JavaDB and when I'm trying to run a SQL query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase ORDER BY colname DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

and try to execute the commend, the console displays an error, namely:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "limit" at line 1, column 55.
```

Any ideas on what I can do? Do you see something wrong with my query code?

Comment: What database are you using? MS SQL doesn't support LIMIT.

Comment: I'm using JavaDB. Will edit orig. Question.

Comment: What does which IDE you use have to do with a SQL error?

Comment: The Netbeans IDE has a SQL Query function in which I type above mentioned query. That's just for debugging. When doing the actual Java command, viz. `String sql="select * from mydatabase order by colname desc limit 0,1"', I also get an error. This error is similar to the debug error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consult the Derby FAQ at http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#limit

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydatabase 
ORDER BY colname DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

[Reference](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html)